# Power BI/Power Query Error: A circular dependency was detected in deduplicate strings count

Tags: string, powerbi, distinct, powerquery

I have a string column, which I want to count distinct/deduplicate strings in Power Query, such as below:

| Content |
| --- |
| "StringOne" |
| "StringTwo" |
| "StringOne" |
| "StringThree" |

**And what I want a count of each unique string, something like this: [StringOne + StringTwo + StringThree + (StringOne - StringOne)]**

| Content | SumMessageTag |
| --- | --- |
| StringOne | 3 |
| StringTwo | 3 |
| StringOne | 3 |
| StringThree | 3 |

So the Distinct Count should sum to 3, not 4

Here's what I have so far:

```
SumMessageTag = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(data[Content]), data[Content])
```

And the error that comes up is: A circular dependency was detected.

Here's what's recommended from the Power BI for *numeric* values:

```
SumMessageTag = SUMX(DISTINCT(Table1[number]), Table1[number])
```

But SUMX doesn't work with strings.

And using:

```
SumMessageTag = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(data[Content]))
```

returns:

| Content | SumMessageTag |
| --- | --- |
| StringOne | 1 |
| StringTwo | 1 |
| StringOne | 1 |
| StringThree | 1 |

Which is not what I want either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an option that works:

```
SumMessageTag = COUNTROWS(DISTINCT(data[Content]))
```

Which provides the count I want.